# swap values between columns using R

Tags: r, normalization

I have a dataset called `cloud` which looks as follows:

```
"Rainfall, Treatment
274.7, Seeded
274.7, Seeded
Seeded, 255
242.5, Seeded
200.7, Seeded
198.6, Seeded
129.6, Seeded
119, Seeded
118.3, Seeded
115.3, Seeded
92.4, Seeded
40.6, Seeded
32.7, Seeded
31.4, Seded
17.5, Seeded"
```

Can anyone help me to:

1. Swap the data in where the values are misplaced (i.e. `Rainfall == "Seeded"` and `Treatment == 255` should be swapped); and
2. Correct the spelling of the value in `Treatment == "Seded"` to `"Seeded"`

Comment: Read about subsetting dataframes in R. For your cases if the row number is fixed, you can do `cloud[38, "Rainfall"] <- 255` and `cloud[38, "Treatment"] <- "Seeded"`. Similarly, you can also change the spelling at row 49.

Comment: Thnak you @RonakShah, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

I stored the misplaced values in two separate vectors. Then used three `dplyr::if_else()` calls inside of `dplyr::mutate()` to clean the variables as desired.

```
# load necessary packages -----
library(tidyverse)

# load necessary data --------
cloud <-
  read_csv("Rainfall, Treatment
274.7, Seeded
           274.7, Seeded
           Seeded, 255
           242.5, Seeded
           200.7, Seeded
           198.6, Seeded
           129.6, Seeded
           119, Seeded
           118.3, Seeded
           115.3, Seeded
           92.4, Seeded
           40.6, Seeded
           32.7, Seeded
           31.4, Seded
           17.5, Seeded")

# store the misplaced text value
misplaced.text <-
  cloud %>% pull(Rainfall) %>% str_subset("^\\D.*$")

# store the misplaced numeric value
misplaced.numeric <-
  cloud %>% pull(Treatment) %>% str_subset("^\\d.*$")

# update cloud so that misplaced values are swapped -----
# and clean Treatment for mispellings
cloud.clean <-
  cloud %>%
  mutate(Rainfall = if_else(Rainfall %in% misplaced.text &
                              Treatment %in%  misplaced.numeric
                            , misplaced.numeric
                            , Rainfall) %>% as.double()
         , Treatment = if_else(Treatment %in%  misplaced.numeric
                               , misplaced.text
                               , Treatment)
         , Treatment = if_else(Treatment %in% "Seded"
                               , "Seeded"
                               , Treatment))

# view results ----
# note: tibble is only rounding the printed output in console
cloud.clean$Rainfall[1] # [1] 274.7
cloud.clean
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Rainfall Treatment
#        <dbl> <chr>    
#  1    275.  Seeded   
#  2    275.  Seeded   
#  3    255   Seeded   
#  4    242.  Seeded   
#  5    201.  Seeded   
#  6    199.  Seeded   
#  7    130.  Seeded   
#  8    119   Seeded   
#  9    118.  Seeded   
# 10    115.  Seeded   
# 11     92.4 Seeded   
# 12     40.6 Seeded   
# 13     32.7 Seeded   
# 14     31.4 Seeded   
# 15     17.5 Seeded  

# end of script #
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a temp figure to swap

```
temp                <- cloud$Treatment[38]
cloud$Treatment[38] <- cloud$Rainfall[38]
cloud$Rainfall[38]  <- temp
temp                <- NULL
```

You can also use this method to change the spelling:

```
cloud$Treatment[49] <- "Seeded"
```

Comment: thank you, when I tried this I got a message `invalid factor level, NA generated` and in `cloud$Rainfall[38]` is initiated with `NA`, but there should be `255`

Answer (score 0):

Using a smaller example

```
df <- data.frame(Rainfall=c('Seeded', '31.4'),
                 Treatment=c('255', 'Seded'),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df

  Rainfall Treatment
1   Seeded       255
2     31.4     Seded
```

a possible solution:

```
# Swap values from col/col2 on row 1 (changing col order)
df[1, c(1,2)] <- df[1, c(2,1)]
# Rename Treatment value on row 2
df[2, c("Treatment")] <- 'Seeded'

df 

  Rainfall Treatment
1      255    Seeded
2     31.4    Seeded
```